# Recovering image header from a corrupt PNG

Tags: crc

I'm working on a pentesting challenge in which a corrupt PNG is provided with the eight dimension bytes in the IHDR chunk all set to zero. The CRC checksum and the rest of the file is still intact. I was wondering whether there is a way to recover the image dimensions by somehow reversing the CRC, since as I understand it, the CRC is calculated from the chunk's bytes. If this is not possible, is there some other way to find the dimensions based on the image data? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe share the *"unhappy"* PNG - you'll need to use Dropbox or Google Drive or similar if it is corrupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no, you cannot recover 62 bits of information from a 32-bit CRC. (It's 62 and not 64 because the specification limits the range of each to 1..2<sup>31</sup>.)

However, if you assume that the image width and height are both constrained to fit in 16 bits each, say 1..65535, then it can be done with just the CRC. [spoof](https://github.com/madler/spoof) will do this for you, where you provide those bit locations and the exclusive-or of the CRC of the header that's there, with the zeroed-out width and height, and the CRC stored in the header, asserted to be the CRC of the header when it contained the original width and height. spoof does this by solving the linear equations over GF(2) of 32 equations in 32 unknowns.

This can be solved in general for very large images if you also make use of the image data, asserted to be intact. Using the rest of the header information and decoding the image data, you would factor the integer number of total bytes in the decompressed data into its prime decomposition. You will then have a small number of possible factorizations into rows and columns. You can try each of those back in the header to see which matches the CRC. Some may be ruled out even before checking the CRC, since the number of bytes in a row has to be one plus a multiple of the bytes per pixel, e.g. three for an RGB image or four for RGBA. (In fact, for the corrupted image originally provided in the question, there is only one factorization that meets that constraint, which is the answer.)

In the incredibly unlikely case that more than one of those matches the CRC, you can use each to decompress the image and see which one looks right. The others will likely look terribly skewed, like an old television that is unable to lock onto the horizontal sync from the received signal.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this great answer. In all honesty, though, I wasn't expecting the solution to the challenge and I was just trying to see whether my approach was valid. In case other people doing the same challenge come across this post, would you mind removing the fixed image?

Comment: Ah, ok. Will do. I have no idea what "pentesting" is.